# Как добавить тень и разделить анимацию у объектов?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Необходимо добавить тень на карточки товара, а также разделить срабатывание анимации у всех карточек сразу. Сейчас, если навестись на "Подробнее", анимация срабатывает у всех трёх карточек.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-item {
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: inline;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.product-item img {
  padding: 0 44px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-list {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 15px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.product-list h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #545454;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.price {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #545454;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background-image: url('/img/button.png');
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}

.product-item:hover .button {
  background-image: url('/img/Button-hover.png');
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item">
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Landing<br>page</h3>
    <img class="product" src="/img/product1.svg">
    <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 1.500 руб.</span>
    <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Мини<br>магазин</h3>
    <img class="product" src="/img/product2.svg">
    <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 4.000 руб.</span>
    <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Большой<br>сайт</h3>
    <img class="product" src="/img/product3.svg">
    <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 8.000 руб.</span>
    <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как это должно выглядеть: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что вызвало у Вас проблемы при добавлении тени ?

Comment: Тень отображается не корректно, 
вот, как я прописываю тень:
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
Вот как она отображается (https://i.imgur.com/u1Bq2Iq.png)

Comment: Вы классы не правильно проставили, по этому срабатывает на все карточки.

Comment: Хорошо, а можете подсказать в каком расставить классы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это код с учётом предыдущего вопроса касательно расстояния между карточками в 105px

```
    <div class="product-item">
       <div class="product-list">
           <h3>Landing<br>page</h3>
           <img class="product" src="/img/product1.svg">
           <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 1.500 руб.</span>
           <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-list">
            <h3>Мини<br>магазин</h3>
            <img class="product" src="/img/product2.svg">
            <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 4.000 руб.</span>
            <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-list">
          <h3>Большой<br>сайт</h3>
          <img class="product" src="/img/product3.svg">
          <span class="price">Цена:<br>от 8.000 руб.</span>
          <a href="" class="button">Подробнее</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .product-item {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
 }
 .product-item img {
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 80%;
 }
 .product-list {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #E1E1E1;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-right: 105px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)
 }
 .product-list h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #545454;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
 }
 .price {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #545454;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 .button {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 30px;
    background-image: url('/img/button.png');
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 30px;
    transition: .3s ease-in;
 }
 .button:hover  {
    background-image: url('/img/Button-hover.png');
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);/*Для наглядности удалить если не надо*/
    border-radius: 15px;/*радиус и так 15px у класса .button*/
 }

.product-list:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!